# git push falsely claims 'Everything up-to-date'

Tags: git, ssh, git-push

I have configured git so that I can push my local dev-repository to my web server via SSH using public keys. The bare repository on the server is set up with a post-receive hook that checks out all the files into the right location.

It all worked nicely until today I manually changed the permissions of some files on the server. After trying the command

git push web

again, it gave me a lot of permission errors because it couldn't access the remote repository files. So I changed the permissions back to what they were before and tried again. However, now it says 'Everything up-to-date' but the newer version is not on my server yet.

What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that the repo is updated and the post-receive failed due to permission issue like you mentioned. Easiest way to fix would be to make one more commit and push. Or go on server and just run the post-receive yourself.

Note that the post-receive does not affect the outcome of the push and hence even if it fails the push is still done. That is why you are observing this.

Comment: To clarify: "everything up-to-date" is Git saying, yes, you've pushed the most recent commits into this bare repository. It doesn't have anything to do with your hook, which only runs after a push that changes things. Your push doesn't change anything, so your hook doesn't run, so nothing gets checked out on your web server.

Comment: thanks, what I did was to manually run the post-receive hook and it then copied over the missing files.